# Como usar o await no lugar do .then() no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async, async-await

Tenho esse código assíncrono:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));


async function umPorSegundo(){
    console.log(await delay(), '1s')
    console.log(await delay(), '2s')
    console.log(await delay(), '3s')
}

umPorSegundo();
```

O `delay` é feito corretamente, mas o console sempre retorna `undefined` antes. Como fazer ele retornar apenas os segundos?

Comment: `console.log(await delay() || '1s');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O console está logando `undefined` porque a função `delay` não retorna nada (o que é `undefined`).

Por exemplo:

```js
function test() {
  // Não retorna nada.
}

console.log(test()); // undefined
```

Se você quiser modificar a função `delay` para retornar os segundos, precisará alterar o código dela:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(1000), 1000));
```

Nesse caso, a `Promise` estará resolvendo o valor `1000` (1000 milissegundos é igual a 1 segundo). Você pode modificar o `resolve` para que a promessa resolva qualquer outro valor...

Para saber mais sobre as `Promise`s, [leia aqui](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-BR).